# How to access json array that is passed from restful web service in android?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, arrays

I have successfully created a rest web service and it returns jsonarray which has two fields 
id and city from data base.

```
My resr web service is
```

@GET

```
@Path("city")

@Produces("application/json")

public String getJson() {

    PropertyPojo propojo=null;

    ArrayList cityList = new ArrayList();

    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

     Map m1 = new LinkedHashMap();

     List  l1 = new LinkedList();

     String jsonString = null;

    try{
        cityList=PDao.CityList();
         Iterator it=cityList.iterator();

                while(it.hasNext())
                 {
                    propojo=(PropertyPojo)it.next();

                    m1.put(propojo.getKeyid(),propojo.getKeyvalue());

                 }


    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    l1.add(m1);
    jsonString = JSONValue.toJSONString(l1);
    return jsonString;
}
```

I just need to put these values into a spinner...

**My android code is**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner spinner;

    private static final String SERVICE_URL = "http://192.168.1.6:8080/eSava_RestWeb/webresources/service";

    private static final String TAG = "AndroidRESTClientActivity";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.city);
    }

    public void retrieveSampleData(View vw) {

        String sampleURL = SERVICE_URL + "/city";

        WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.GET_TASK,
                this, "GETting data...");

        wst.execute(new String[] { sampleURL });

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void handleResponse(String response) {

        try {
            // JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) json;
            if (jsonArray != null) {
                int len = jsonArray.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                }
            }

            Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.city);
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            s.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }

    }

    private class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        public static final int POST_TASK = 1;
        public static final int GET_TASK = 2;

        private static final String TAG = "WebServiceTask";

        // connection timeout, in milliseconds (waiting to connect)
        private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 3000;

        // socket timeout, in milliseconds (waiting for data)
        private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;

        private int taskType = GET_TASK;
        private Context mContext = null;
        private String processMessage = "Processing...";

        private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        private ProgressDialog pDlg = null;

        public WebServiceTask(int taskType, Context mContext,
                String processMessage) {

            this.taskType = taskType;
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.processMessage = processMessage;
        }

        public void addNameValuePair(String name, String value) {

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
        }

        private void showProgressDialog() {

            pDlg = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            pDlg.setMessage(processMessage);
            pDlg.setProgressDrawable(mContext.getWallpaper());
            pDlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDlg.setCancelable(false);
            pDlg.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            showProgressDialog();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String url = urls[0];
            String result = "";

            HttpResponse response = doResponse(url);

            if (response == null) {
                return result;
            } else {

                try {

                    result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity()
                            .getContent());

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                }

            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            JSONArray jsArray;
            // jsArray = new JSONArray(response);
            handleResponse(response);
            pDlg.dismiss();

        }

        // Establish connection and socket (data retrieval) timeouts
        private HttpParams getHttpParams() {

            HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, CONN_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

            return htpp;
        }

        private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {

            // Use our connection and data timeouts as parameters for our
            // DefaultHttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());

            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                switch (taskType) {

                case POST_TASK:
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                    // Add parameters
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    break;
                case GET_TASK:
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

            }

            return response;
        }

        private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

            // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                // Read response until the end
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }

            // Return full string
            return total.toString();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to create Model class and then you can parse the response with gson.

For example,

Imagine that you have your response with two strings Name and Mail. Create a model with two strings.

```
public class Sample{
  public Sample()
  {

  }
  @SerializedName("Name")//if needed
  String name;
  @SerializedName("Email")//if needed
  String email;
  public void set(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

  public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
  public void set(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

  public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

Then parse your response with gson.

```
Sample sample = gson.fromJson(jsonRes.toString(), Sample.class);
```

Then you can access the members of the object sample. Change the Sample class as you needed(with the array of strings and int. You can use ArrayList instead of Array)

Comment: it gives the error - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY because my response is jsonarray JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

Comment: Yes, you can change the Sample class as you needed. Can you give me the structure of your Json result?

Comment: [{"1":"TRIVANDRUM","2":"KANNUR"}] where key_id is 1 keycalue is TRIVANDRUM and do on....

Comment: Why you are using the key as a dynamic one? Its better to change the key as static. If you want the key then you can change your json structure to {
    "citylist": [
        {
            "city_id": 1,
            "city_name": "TRIVANDRUM"
        },
        {
            "city_id": 2,
            "city_name": "KANNUR"
        },
        {
            "city_id": 3,
            "city_name": "MADURAI"
        }
    ]
}
then it will be easy to parse

Comment: Can you please give me the code in web service I searched a lot but I could not find it.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Make an object with the values city_id and city_value, add it to an arraylist city_list. Then send the arraylist as response for the request. Thats it..

Comment: [{"city_id":1,"city_name":"TRIVANDRUM"},{"city_id":2,"city_name":"KANNUR"}] I got this way how can I parse it to display it in spinner. when I select TRIVANDRUM from spinner I should get 1 as the value...

Comment: Now you can parse the Json object then you can have a list of cities. Add the city_name to an arraylist then show it in the spinner. And get  the selected position of the spinner. Now you can get the item from the citylist which is in the selected position. Then you can get the id alone from the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] city= {};
String[] id= {};

JSONArray jsonDetailsObj = json.getJSONArray("cityList");
JSONObject jsonLoop = null; 
int noOfPoints = jsonDetailsObj.length();

city= new String[noOfPoints];
id= new String[noOfPoints];


for (int i=0 ; i < noOfPoints ; i++)
{
   jsonLoop=jsonDetailsObj.getJSONObject(i);
   city [i] = jsonLoop.getString("CityName");
   id[i] = jsonLoop.getString("ID");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but It show the error -The method getJSONArray(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String) in the 3rd line in your post..

Comment: Try as in your original code: JSONArray jsonDetailsObj = json.getJSONArray(cityList);  (Without quotes)